# How to check if a record was once before false before becomming true

Tags: mysql

I want get the record if `IsGood` changes for the same `bike` at a different `station` in this example I should get only the 3th record back.

| bike | time | IsGood | station |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 20170623T164400 | 0 (means flase) | 10 |
| 5 | 20170623T155500 | 0 (means false) | 20 |
| 5 | 20170710T141200 | 1 (means true) | 30 |
| 5 | 20180710T141200 | 1 (means true) | 20 |

Comment: did you try to implement Trigger?

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez No, do you have a good sources how to do that and how that would work in this example?